# Blender Eevee, When i go to render mode i have lights but when i accually render it, the light is gone

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

All My graphics card is updated, i just wanted to make a video, but this happen

Specs : Blender 2.93.3, Eevee render.

Problem : Has light in render mode but no light when accually gets rendered

Hope Somebody can come up with a solution :)[image]

[image]

Comment: I can see that your lights are visible in render but is everything that should be visible visible in render as well? If yes it probably is that you must have forgot something or did some little mistake that may have caused this. GPU is surely not the problem because you can see some lights

Comment: can you share your scene? Delete everything that is too big to transfer or personal and share your scene and those lights

Answer (score 5):

I see a lot of collections, which is disabled in viewport but active in render.
One collection has a big amount of light sources. I think you don't know that currently [EEVEE is limited by 128 light sources](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/limitations.html#:%7E:text=are%20currently%20supported.-,Lights,supported%20at%20the%20same%20time.), so then the collection with light sources is enabled during render, you simply run out of light sources.

Probably, you should either disable hidden collections in render too (click on photo camera icon where eye icon is disabled) or disable collection using checkmark icon (both ways should work):

[image]

Comment: woah, didn't know about 128 lights, great info +1